# ¿como se hace para que un programa en c se elimine al acabar de ejecutarse?

Tags: c

Necesito que al terminar un programa hecho en c se elimine el archivo ".exe".
Desde el mismo archivo .exe creo que no se puede hacer asique he intentado hacer un segundo que al ejecutarse 1 segundo despues borre el archivo pero no se como hacer para que lo abra el primer programa antes de acabar. Lo he intentado con shellexecute y se abre el programa de borrado pero no borra el archivo. Sinembargo si lo abro yo manualmente si lo borra. Y preferiría no hacerlo con system() porque quiero que lo haga de manera oculta y al usar system se me abre la consola del cmd.

Comment: Puedo preguntar para que quieres hacer eso? Porque quieres hacerlo de forma oculta? No me huele que lleves buenas intenciones con tu programa.

Comment: @Pablochaches No tiene malas intenciones. Esque acabo de empezar a programar hace poco y he empezado aprendiendo C. El programa es solo para aprender y usarlo solo yo en mi ordenador además que lo unico que hace es copiar una carpeta en otro sitio y no quiero que salga la consola porque queda feo XD. Tambien esque con la consola sin ocultar se hacerlo porque así fue como lo hice al principio pero con ella oculta no se asique me entró curiosidad y pregunté aqui a ver si alguien me podía enseñar.

Comment: Te sere honesto, no se como hacerlo. Pero un buen lugar para empezar es por la API de windows.

Comment: Gracias cuando tenga tiempo lo miro. Esque las funciones que he encontrado abren el archivo pero hasta que no se termina de ejecutar el segundo no se cierra el primero. Asique el segundo no puede borrar el primero. A ver si hay suerte y ve la pregunta alguien que conozca alguna manera.

Comment: No hace falta eliminar el archivo `.exe`. Simplemente no uses funciones para pausar el programa como `getchar()` o `getch()` y la consola se cerrará cuando el programa haga lo que deba hacer.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Eso es lo que tengo hecho pero Estoy usando codebloks y he cambiado en propiedades de aplicación de aplicacion de consola a aplicacion gui para que no aparezca la consola cuando lo ejecutas. y mi duda es si cuando acabe de ejecutarse puedo eliminarlo o no de alguna manera.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que crees un archivo .bat y desde ahi ejecutes tu .exe al final de la operación de tu programa que el archivo .bat lo elimine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final he conseguido hacerlo. Dejo aqui el código por si a alguien le interesa lo unico que hay que hacer es poner las librerías , copiar el void y cambiar el nombre_programa.exe por el nombre de tu programa XD. Lo único que no se es si el timeout en el bat es necesario pero yo lo pongo por si acaso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>

void autoeliminacion();

int main()
{
    autoeliminacion();
    return 0;
}

void autoeliminacion()
{
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("borrar.bat","wt");
    fprintf(f,"Taskkill /IM nombre_programa.exe /F\n");
    fprintf(f,"TIMEOUT /T 0.3\n");
    fprintf(f,"DEL nombre_programa.exe\n");
    fprintf(f,"DEL borrar.bat\n");
    fclose(f);
    ShellExecuteA(GetDesktopWindow(),"open","borrar.bat",NULL,NULL,CREATE_NO_WINDOW);
}
```